# Enable IDT High Definition Audio Codec hardware enhanced sound

Tags: sound

I brought a new HP pavilion 6g 2301ek laptop and among the driver problems I encountered (which I couldn't solve) is the IDT hardware enhancement. On Windows, using the generic sound driver, the sound output is the same as in Ubuntu now. Right after installing the IDT driver on windows, it could enable the Dolby hardware enhancement, I couldn't do the same on Ubuntu. Any solutions?

I couldn't find any driver on the net, some people suggested software solutions but i need to use the integrated hardware for this.
I'm using ubuntu raring 64bit version.

### some outputs

#### cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#* | grep Codec

```
Codec: IDT 92HD87B2/4
Codec: Intel PantherPoint HDMI
```

#### aplay -L

```
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
sysdefault:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, STAC92xx Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, STAC92xx Analog
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, STAC92xx Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, STAC92xx Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, STAC92xx Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, STAC92xx Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, STAC92xx Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, STAC92xx Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=3
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, STAC92xx Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=3
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, STAC92xx Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=3
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, STAC92xx Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=3
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

#### lspci -nn | grep -i audio

```
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
```

Comment: Exactly why doesn't work?

Comment: sound works properly, but the dolby surround isn't. The sound the speakers should make is way better (as on windows with dolby driver)

Comment: still a problem in 2017. workaround is to set volume to %150 but you will get a little distortion and it wont be as loud as windows